# Symfony6/Doctrine: when flushing, check if record of relation already exists

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have several entities with several relations. They have one "starting" entity. When I want to persist data to my database, I set the data to each entity (implicitly with a method I wrote, because I import that data from an xml), but only persist and flush the main entity. I used cascade:persist in the entities accordingly. And all that works just fine.

But: There are entities (the OneToMany side) that should check in the database, whether or not the record already exists and only set a new record, if not. And if the record exists the ManyToOne side should get that foreign key, that already exists.

Is there an easy way to tell doctrine to do so on my single persist/flush of the main entity?

**edit**
Maybe I can simplify the question to:
Is it possible to flush an object and doctrine will check if this record already exists in the database (in one query)? Or do I have to do make a query to check for existing records first and then a second query with my data to be set?
**edit end**

Thanks a lot for your help

David

Comment: Nope.  If I understand the problem description (code. is often more useful than prose), you will need to query the database to determine if a given entity already exists.  It's a common requirement when importing.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks for your help. :)